# How to change HTTP header of a SOAP request?

Tags: php, http, soap, zend-framework, header

I send SOAP request in PHP, but the server SOAP need an apikey. This apikey 
should be placed in the header of the http request.

```
$context = stream_context_create(array(
'http' => array(
    'method' => 'GET',
    'header' => 'Content-type: text/xml\r\n'.
    'apikey: *************************************\r\n'
    )
));

$options = array(   
'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE,
'trace' => 1,
'soap_version' => SOAP_1_1,
'exceptions' => true,
'stream_context' => $context
);

$client = new SoapClient("file wsdl", $options);
```

But this is the result :

```
POST **************.wsdl HTTP/1.1
Host: ************************
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: PHP-SOAP/5.6.31
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
SOAPAction: ""
Content-Length: 989
```

As you can see, the request header doesn't contains the apikey. I also tryed to use the zendsoap function.

My config :
- windows 8
- wamp 3.1.0
- php 5.6.31

Have you any clue to help me resolve this issue?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You need to send the `apiKey` as part of the request header.

You should try something like this:

`'header' => 'Content-type: text/xml\r\napikey: *******\r\n'.`

Comment: Thank for your answer. However already tested and result is same.